# Understanding $dateAdd/$dateSubtract behavior in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to understand why `$dateadd` works with `$expr` but not without:

This code returns result set:

```
db.getCollection("CollectionName").aggregate(
[
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "_id" : NumberInt(-1)
        }
    }, 
   {"$match": 
       {"$expr":
              {
                 $gte:
                    [ "$CreateDate",
                      {
                         $dateAdd:
                            {
                               startDate: ISODate(),
                               unit: "hour",
                               amount: -1
                            }
                       }
                    ]
              }
      }
   }
]);
```

While this one is not(empty result set):

```
db.getCollection("CollectionName").aggregate(
[
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "_id" : NumberInt(-1)
        }
    }, 
   {"$match": 
       {"CreateDate": {
                      //"$gte" : ISODate("2023-07-04T12:25:00.000+0000") --works also
                      "$gte" : {$dateAdd:
                                    {
                                       startDate: ISODate(),
                                       unit: "hour",
                                       amount: -1
                                    }
                                }
                      }
                        
       }                    
   }
]);
```

- As I wrote in example, replacing `$dateadd` with hard coded value works also.
- MongoDB version is 5.0.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [$match](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)

> The query syntax is identical to the read operation query syntax; i.e. `$match` does not accept raw aggregation expressions. Instead, use a `$expr` query expression to include aggregation expression in `$match`.

Functions like `$dateAdd` and `$dateSubtract` are aggregation expressions